# How to speed up time when calculate cosine similarity using nested loops in python

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to calculate the cosine similarity between all the values.

The time for 1000*20000 calculations cost me more than 10 mins.

Code:

```
from gensim import matutils
# array_A contains 1,000 TF-IDF values
# array_B contains 20,000 TF-IDF values 
for x in array_A:
   for y in array_B:
      matutils.cossim(x,y)
```

It's necessary to using gensim package to get the tf-idf value and similarity calculation.

Can someone please give me some advice and guidance to speed up time?

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of one of the for loops? Does Cython speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

use memoize and also maybe use tuples (it may be faster) for the arrays:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}

    def helper(a, b):
        if (b, a) in memo: return memo[b, a]
        elif (a, b) in memo: return memo[a, b]
        else:
            memo[(a, b)] = f(a, b)
            return memo[a, b]

    return helper


@memoize
def myfunc(a, b):
    matutils.cossim(x,y)
```

**EDIT**
also after using the code above maybe add this just in case you are doing something else with the data

```
cossim_responses = [myfunc(a, b) for a in array_A for b in array_B]
# you could also do (myfunc(a, b) for a in array_A for b in array_B)
```

Comment: The result shows that " TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' "

Comment: Which code? I updated it so that it says a, b instead of a, a now

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source for gensim's `matutils.cossim()`:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/2e58a1c899af05ee6a39a1dd1c49dd6641501a9c/gensim/matutils.py#L436

You'll see it's doing a bit of work on its two (sparse-array) arguments to move their non-zero dimensions into temporary dicts, then calculating their lengths – which is repeated every time the same vector is supplied in your loops.

You might get a reasonable speedup by doing those steps on each vector only once, and remembering those dicts & lengths for re-use on each final pairwise calculation. (That is, memoizing the interim values, rather than just the final values.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nmslib](https://github.com/nmslib/nmslib) or [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss) for vector search operations